# com.tangosol.net.ssl.SSLSocketProvider is missing in coherence 12.1.3

Tags: ssl, oracle-coherence

The package com.tangosol.net.ssl.SSLSocketProvider that was in coherence 3.7.1 is missing in coherence 12.1.3.0 version. I have used a class extending the SSLSocketProvider class for SSL Handshake. What is the alternative that is provided in coherence 12.1.3.0 for this functionality?

Answer (score -1):

This class is intended for internal usage only.  If you've still com.oracle.common-net.  There may be some API "tweaks" as well.  If you are using this class, I suggest contacting me to see if the use can be replaced by an external API.

craig.blitz@oracle.com, Director of Product Management, Oracle Coherence

Comment: Should anyone who has the same question contact you?